# How to avoid E0637 in trait bound without triggering lifetime issues and without using owned values?

Tags: rust

This issue is best described with [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=edbd13b4cf1536b04557ec101aadd7a7).

```rust
struct Foo;

impl From<&[u8]> for Foo {
    fn from(_: &[u8]) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}
```

What's in `main()` is proven to work, but I don't know how I can express that within the generic function without triggering compiler error E0637.

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![0u8]; // <-- works!
    Foo::from(v.as_slice());
}

fn trigger_lifetime_issue_but_not_e637<'a, T>() 
where
    T: From<&'a[u8]> {
    let v = vec![0u8];
    T::from(v.as_slice()); // <-- Doesn't work because 'a is enforced by E0637
}
```

When trying to learn more about E0637 in search for a solution/alternative, I have to read between the lines.

[image: a screenshot of the rust compiler error help page]

This issue occours in a real work program, and I work around this [with unnecessary owned values](https://github.com/crates-io/criner/blob/90b86e12d6225c1666e7ee47c24ce6b8ea37b36a/criner/src/export.rs#L24-L23).

**How can I use `T: From<&[u8]>` in a trait bound without triggering lifetime issues while avoiding E0637?**

Comment: The provided Playground triggers E0597 with the latest Stable toolchain, not E0637. Would you like to double-check on this? Or are you saying that some other version of your code can trigger the latter?

Comment: @SCappella Yes :)! This answers the question. Here is a playground link which applies the locally scoped lifetime: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ff94277e6d146b87e8640e4bee8644d